# Writting optimization problems side by side

Tags: equations, align

I'd like to end up with something similar to

[image: this]

but nicer looking, as the alignement does not look right. I'd like the second column to look much like the first one. Also, I believe that I could use the `align*` environment rather than nesting `equation*` and `aligned`. Is it preferable to do either one?

The code I'm using is

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
         &\max\limits_{\{q_i\}} \sum_{i=1}^n q_i & & &\max\limits_{\{q_i\}} \sum_{i=1}^n q_i\\
         \text{s.t.}  & \begin{cases}\mathbf{A}^{\top}\mathbf{q}^\beta\leq\mathbf{k}\\ \mathbf{q}\geq 0\end{cases}& &\text{s.t.} &\begin{cases}\mathbf{A}^{\top}\mathbf{q}^\beta=\mathbf{k}\\ \mathbf{q}\geq 0\end{cases}
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every second `&` starts a new column.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  &\max\limits_{\{q_i\}} \sum_{i=1}^n q_i &
  &\max\limits_{\{q_i\}} \sum_{i=1}^n q_i \\
  \text{s.t.} & \begin{cases}\mathbf{A}^{\top}\mathbf{q}^\beta\leq\mathbf{k}\\ \mathbf{q}\geq 0\end{cases} &
  \text{s.t.} & \begin{cases}\mathbf{A}^{\top}\mathbf{q}^\beta=\mathbf{k}\\ \mathbf{q}\geq 0\end{cases}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Nice and simple. It is very similar to what I was doing. Why is the alignment so different in yours?

Comment: You have three columns instead of 2: too many &s.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with `align*` and `gathered`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    & \begin{gathered}
         \max_{\{q_i\}} \sum_{i=1}^n q_i\\
         \text{s.t.}
          \begin{cases}\mathbf{A}^{\!\top}\mathbf{q}^\beta\leq\mathbf{k}\\ \mathbf{q}\geq 0\end{cases}
       \end{gathered}
        & & \begin{gathered}
                \max_{\{q_i\}} \sum_{i=1}^n q_i \\
                \text{s.t.} \begin{cases}\mathbf{A}^{\!\top}\mathbf{q}^\beta=\mathbf{k}\\ \mathbf{q}\geq 0\end{cases}
               \end{gathered}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]